# Point Process as a Random Distribution of Indistinguishable Points

Tags: measure-theory, point-processes

I am currently reading *Point Processes and Their Statistical Inference (2nd Edition)* and had a question about how point processes are defined on page 5.

So a point process on $E$ is defined as a measurable mapping $N$ of $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ into $(\mathbf{M}_p,\mathcal{M}_p)$ where

- $\mathbf{M}=$ set of all Radon measures
- $\mathbf{M}_p=\{\mu\in \mathbf{M}\;| \; \mu(A) \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall \; A \in \mathcal{B}\}$
- $\mathcal{B}$ the ring of bounded Borel sets
- $\mathcal{M}_p$ the trace sigma algebra on $\mathbf{M}_p$

Point processes are then described as follows. "A point process $N$ is a random distribution of indistinguishable points in $E$: $N(A)$ is the number of points in the set $A$". Earlier in the chapter it says that "a point process is a model of points randomly distributed in some space; they are indistinguishable except for their locations".

I am trying to understand what is meant here by "indistinguishable" since generally when you see a realization of a point process it gives you a set of points that are distinct. Wikipedia says two points are indistinguishable is they have the same neighbourhood, so to me it seems it should be a distribution of distinguishable points in $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For clarification**: I am using the term *element* when talking about an element of a set, and the term *point*, when talking about a unit of measure assigned to a set by a point process.

When $E$ is an abstract topological space, it could be that two elements — as in „two distinct elements of the topological space“ — are not distinguishable with respect to the topology. This is the case, if any neighbourhood of one point is also a neighbourhood of the other.

To construct an example, let $E= \{x,y\}$, and let the topology be $O= \{\emptyset, E\}$. Then $E$ is the only neighbourhood of each element, and both elements have the same neighbourhoods.

A point process now randomly assigns mass to the open sets (only E) of the topology. Let‘s say for example, that in one realization, it assigns the value 2 to $E$. Then we know, that there are two points in the set $\{x,y\}$. But we don‘t know, if the two points are $x$ and $y$, or maybe $x$ twice, or $y$ twice. We only know that two points in $\{x,y\}$ were randomly chosen.

**Note**: One often assumes the topology on $E$ to be rich enough so that one can distinguish all the elements. Any *Hausdorff* space would do just fine.

Comment: So I guess what you are saying is that a point process specifies for some open set $A$ in the topology the probability of what the number of points are, but not what the specific points will be? E.g. if $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $N(A)=2$, the point process does not specify how likely each set of 2 points in $A$ is?

Comment: Yes. The point process assigns to each measurable set some mass. In your example, two points lie in the set $A$. If the set $\{c\}\in\mathcal B$ — that is, if it would be measurable — then we would know, how many points lie in this set. In other words, we would know how many points in the realization of the point process $N$ „are“ $c$.

Comment: OK so just to confirm I understand. Let's say $\mathcal{B}=\{\emptyset,\{a,b,c,d\},\{c\},\{a,b,d\}\}$. We draw one realization of $N$, and we might get something like $N(\{a,b,c,d\})=3,\;N(\{c\})=1,\;N(\{a,b,d\})=2$. So here we would know for sure that $c$ is one of the points selected, and between $a,b,d$ two of the points are selected. In this case $a,b,d$ are indistinguishable in that the point process does not actually define the probability distribution of which two of these points got selected.

Comment: Exactly! Keep in mind, that $N\{c\} =2$ is also a possible realization, even thought the set does only contain one element. But I think you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What then does define the probability of which of the indistinguishable points get selected. I am guessing we do not assume it is uniform. Or is it simply something we assume is unknowable/undefined?

Comment: This depends on your interpretation of a realization of the point process. The mathematical model itself does not yield a distribution for which of the indistinguishable points get chosen. If you want to distinguish between the points, then use a finer topology.